# Why do I have to specify datatype when adding a NOT NULL constraint?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For the following table :

```
CREATE TABLE Sucursal
(
    DscSucursal VARCHAR(20),
    DirSucursal VARCHAR(25)
);
```

I want to add a `NOT NULL` constraint to the first column.

According to this source : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-alter-command.htm

I have to tell the constraint the datatype of the column. Why?

The datatype is already defined on the table creation. Why do I have to tell the constraint the datatype ? Isn't this redundant ?

"The basic syntax of an ALTER TABLE command to add a NOT NULL constraint to a column in a table is as follows:"

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
    MODIFY column_name datatype NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Well, I don't know what those who defined it like that had in mind... but from a certain perspective this is just logical. That is, if you consider looking at the datatype as the set of possible values for an attribute. If there's a not null constraint it's one value less -- `NULL` -- otherwise it's included.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: @marc_s: that might be true for some DBMS, but e.g. for Postgres or Oracle you do not need to repeat the data type (and the tag "SQL" does not specify a concrete DBMS)

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name sql-server

Answer (score 0):

It's because you can change the datatype in addition to adding NOT NULL constraint. If you are not changing the datatype it's somewhat redundant.

Comment: Thanks Vasya, that makes some sense :)